# Why does a mapping update itself when I am not doing anything?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping

The title is a little bit vague but I've seen this contract and tried it on remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Tester {

  struct Account {
    uint256 balance; 
  }

  mapping (address => Account) public accounts;

  function addBalance() public payable {
    Account storage a = accounts[msg.sender];
    a.balance = a.balance + msg.value;

  }


}
```

What happens is the following:
1. I check the value in the mapping and it's `0`
2. I execute the `addBalance` function sending 10 wei
3. I check the value in the mapping and I see it's `10`

How is that possible ? I am not updating the mapping.

Comment: if you dont want to update the map do Account memory a = accounts[msg.sender];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
Account storage a = accounts[msg.sender];
```

...declares a storage *pointer*, which points into the mapping. Therefore, any change you make to `a` is reflected in the mapping.

This is different to a normal "storage variable", which is just a variable that persists in the contract's state (as opposed to a local/memory variable, which does not).

---

**Edit:**

Can't immediately find anything useful in the documentation, but there's this, written by Rob: [Storage Pointers in Solidity](https://blog.b9lab.com/storage-pointers-in-solidity-7dcfaa536089)